# Creating a permanent alias for SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, alias, named-pipes, localdb

I am attempting to set up an alias for Microsoft SQL Server's LocalDB, but the named pipes that are used to link the alias I am creating to the instance of LocalDB change each time my named instance is instantiated. Is there a way to set up a permanent alias for an instance of LocalDB?

For example, I have created an instance of LocalDB from the command line called 'MSSQLLocalDB'.

`sqllocaldb create mssqllocaldb`

Then we start it and ask for info.

```
sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb
sqllocaldb info mssqllocaldb

Name:               mssqllocaldb

Version:            11.0.2318.0

Shared name:

Owner:              COOLNEATRADFOLDER\ryguy

Auto-create:        No

State:              Running

Last start time:    4/9/2018 3:46:16 PM

Instance pipe name: np:\\.\pipe\LOCALDB#4329652A3\tsql\query
```

Using Microsoft's Computer Management tool, we are able to create an alias: referring to the instance of LocalDB we have created by using the named pipes we got from the previous command.

The problem is that the named pipes are renamed every time an instance of the database is created, and TCIP seems to not be supported. Every time the server is restarted (upon computer reload, or a timeout, or manually) one must go through the moderately tedious steps of creating an alias in this same way.

I looked into using a powershell script with guidance from this helpful link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/a69366e6-3270-4562-afa4-84b5a08a612b/setup-a-permanent-alias-for-localdb?forum=sqldatabaseengine

But this requires a bit of hacking, and the solution is a bit buggy (you have to directly mess with the registry).

Is there an easier way to create a permanent alias for an instance of LocalDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I found for creating a permanent alias for an instance of MS SQL LocalDB. I have called my instance 'mssqllocaldb'. Thios solution has worked for LocalDB 2012 and 2016. I am using SSMS 2017.

After much review I have come to the conclusion that Microsoft has no support for creating a permanent alias that connects to LocalDB. So I wrote a powershell script that can be run easily. I keep it on my desktop and run it when I want to start my database.

The first segment of code elevates permissions in powershell so that this script can hack the registry.

Next we start our database and parse the `sqllocaldb info` command for the named pipes created for this instance of LocalDB.

Finally we hack the registry to apply the alias name to both 64 and 32 bit versions.

Save in a text file as 'whatever.ps1' with this script. Right click and select 'Run With Powershell' each time you want to start the database.

```
# Self-elevate the script if required
if (-Not ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] 'Administrator')) {
 if ([int](Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BuildNumber) -ge 6000) {
  $CommandLine = "-File `"" + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + "`" " + $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
  Start-Process -FilePath PowerShell.exe -Verb Runas -ArgumentList $CommandLine
  Exit
 }
}


[CmdletBinding()]


$Name = "LocalDBAlias"
$SQLServerName = "mssqllocaldb"

sqllocaldb start mssqllocaldb

$ThePipe = ((sqllocaldb info mssqllocaldb | Select-String -Pattern "np") -split ":")[2]

$hive = "localmachine"

$key = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\MSSQLServer\\Client\\ConnectTo"
$key32 = "SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\MSSQLServer\\Client\\ConnectTo"

$reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]$hive, $env:COMPUTERNAME)


$subkey = $reg.OpenSubKey($key, $true)
$subkey32 = $reg.OpenSubKey($key32, $true)


$res = $subkey.GetValue($Name)
$res32 = $subkey32.GetValue($Name)

$CurrentPipe = ($res -split ",")[1]


if ($CurrentPipe -eq $ThePipe)
{
    Write-Output "The $Name alias' named pipes match the current instance of mssqllocaldb."
}
else 
{
    $subkey.SetValue($Name,"DBNMPNTW,$ThePipe")
    $subkey32.SetValue($Name,"DBNMPNTW,$ThePipe")
    Write-Output "The $Name alias for MSSQLLocalDB has been set."
}


$reg.Close()
```

I hope you have found this helpful! Let me know if I have left out any information or if you have any further questions.